# Add a link to windows file share (\\servername\folder\file.txt) as hyperlink in Reporting Services report RDL?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I know how to add a hyperlink to an http:// address, but it doesn't seem to work with file:// address when I want it to point to a file on the file share.

Tried the following:

```
file://\\server\folder\file.txt
file:\\server\folder\file.txt
\\server\folder\file.txt
```

All 3 methods above work in Windows Start Menu's Run... box. But just not in RDL report definition. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The correct `file` URI to `\\server\folder\file.txt` is `file://server/folder/file.txt`. See [File URIs in Windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Windows will recognize file://///server/folder/file.ext as well(note 5 / after file:), which hopefully Reporting Service will handle as an URL. I've not tested it, but Worth a try.